# How to store the value retrieved from Firebase into a variable Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to retrieve the data(customer name, customer ID)from the firebase and store it into the  variables. After that, I want to store the variables data into another firebase path location.

I'm able to call the snapshot and print it but I just can't save the data from firebase into the variables.

```
CollectionReference orderInfo =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orderInfo');
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  String cusName;
  String add;

  void getNameAddress() async {
    final doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user.uid)
        .get();

    cusName = doc['name'];
    add = doc['address1'] + '' + doc['address2'] + '' + doc['address3'];
  }

  Future initializeOrder(BuildContext ctx) {
    getNameAddress();
    return orderInfo.doc(user.uid + 'order').set({
      'orderID': '',
      'cusID': user.uid,
      'cusName': cusName,
      'cusAdd': add,
      'clID': '',
      'clName': null,
      'price': null,
      'selectedDate': null,
      'serviceSelected': null,
      'typeOfService': 'Not selected yet',
    });
  }
```

The intializeOrder() is the function that I use to store the data in another path.

How should I solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `getNameAddress()` function is `async` and the Firestore `set()` method is asynchronous, you need to make your `initializeOrder()` function `async` and use `await` when calling `getNameAddress()`, as follows:

```
  Future<void> initializeOrder(BuildContext ctx) async {
    await getNameAddress();
    return orderInfo.doc(user.uid + 'order').set({
      'orderID': '',
      'cusID': user.uid,
      'cusName': cusName,
      'cusAdd': add,
      'clID': '',
      'clName': null,
      'price': null,
      'selectedDate': null,
      'serviceSelected': null,
      'typeOfService': 'Not selected yet',
    });
  }
```